# Asterisks next to variable names in R MICE

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

I have been doing multiple imputation using MICE in R. When running, some variables in the console appeared to have asterisks next to their name, e.g., x1* x2* x3*. These asterisks started to appear after I added to the predictor matrix a nominal variable with many levels, some of which have very few cases. (Without this variable, there are no asterisks).

I am wondering what this asterisk means. And whether it is a problem?

Comment: Can you post some example code where this happens? I tried to simulate some data using the letters of the alphabet as a covariate and I didn't see any asterisks in the mice output, just a lot of logged events.

Comment: The code is essentially the same as the code that works well... imp <- mice(dat, meth = meth, m = 30, pred = pred, maxit = 200, seed = 71712)

Comment: My predictor matrix is quite large (178 variables; all variables are used as predictors of all variables). Meth is mostly pmm, but there are some polyreg and logreg; there are also composite scores that are accomodated via passive imputation. The number of cases in the dataset is close to 1000. MICE runs fine in that set up. But then I also have a nominal variable - it's actually a cluster variable - with many levels (about 45). Some clusters are very small (one or a few cases), some others are large (up to about 100).

Comment: Treating the cluster variable as a random effect did not work (R was telling me that the matrix is not positive definite; and even when the matrix was fine, there was no convergence). So I decided to treat this cluster variable as a fixed effect, thinking that this would be better than not including it at all in the imputation model. But when I added this variable to the predictor matrix, R started adding * to some (not all) variables when MICE is running in the console.

Comment: (I actually have two cluster variables - one with about 45 clusters and one with about 25 clusters - but adding any one or both of these cluster variables to the MI model produces asterisks).

Comment: To clarify about the predictor matrix -- items within a composite are not used to predict items within other composites; the composite is used instead. So not all variables are used as predictors of all variables.

Answer (score 4):

After digging through the `mice` documentation I found this in the help page for the `estimice` function.

> This functions adds a star to variable names in the mice iteration history to signal that a ridge penalty was added. In that case, it also adds an entry to loggedEvents.

This happens when it was unable to invert the QR or SVD decomposition of the covariate matrix.

So, I think what's happening is that when you include this nominal variable as a predictor for some of those pmm variables the resulting predictor matrix for that variable is either collinear or nearly collinear. `mice` will drop any variables that are exactly collinear, but if they aren't quite collinear it might still lead to a matrix that is nearly linearly dependent and can't be inverted. In that case `mice` adds a small term to the diagonal elements which allows an inverse to be taken and the computation to continue.

Stef Van Buuren's book, https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-modelform.html, section 6.3.2, recommends that no more than 15-25 predictors be used for each incomplete variable because of these multicollinearity and computational problems. I'd recommend reading that section and considering simplifying your predictor matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am not familiar with a ridge penalty, so is it fine that it was added, or is it a problem, in terms of how trustworthy the results of multiple imputation are?

Comment: And thank you for the link! I will look more into how I could simplify the matrix given the number of variables I have.

Comment: The ridge penalty isn't necessarily a problem, but it indicates that the model is borderline on being undefined. It can be a warning that the results are unstable, small changes to the data may lead to large changes in the results. But it's hard to say in general whether that's the case for your data or how trustworthy the results are.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying! I will try multiple MI models to see how sensitive the results will be. Thanks again!